# What practically is constant volume heat addition in SI piston engine?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pistons

Isochoric means constant volume (In SI engine: piston should not move when the spark is ignited). In reality piston always keeps displacing up and down means volume changes. So, how does this make it a Isochoric Heat Addition in power stroke.

Comment: Explain what? Isochoric? Constant volume? or piston?

Comment: This sounds like someone quoted a homework problem from a book.  What work have you done so far on the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: hello there, I edited the question. Please correct me if you feel it unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the *rate* at which heat is added is so fast that the piston has no opportunity to move during the process. Furthermore, when the piston is at the top of its stroke (which is where the heat is added) the crank-and-connecting rod mechanism yields a finite residence time of the piston in that position for a span of crank rotation, which means that even though the crank never stops *rotating*, the piston spends a finite amount of time in an *almost motionless* state at TDC.